# Avoiding unused variables warnings when using assert() in a Release build

Tags: c++, warnings, assertions

Sometimes a local variable is used for the sole purpose of checking it in an assert(), like so -

```
int Result = Func();
assert( Result == 1 );
```

When compiling code in a Release build, assert()s are usually disabled, so this code may produce a warning about Result being set but never read.

A possible workaround is -

```
int Result = Func();
if ( Result == 1 )
{
    assert( 0 );
}
```

But it requires too much typing, isn't easy on the eyes and causes the condition to be always checked (yes, the compiler may optimize the check away, but still).

I'm looking for an alternative way to express this assert() in a way that wouldn't cause the warning, but still be simple to use and avoid changing the semantics of assert().

(disabling the warning using a #pragma in this region of code isn't an option, and lowering warning levels to make it go away isn't an option either...).

Comment: superset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599160/how-to-suppress-unused-parameter-warnings-in-c/12891181

Answer (score 62, accepted):

We use a macro to specifically indicate when something is unused:

```
#define _unused(x) ((void)(x))
```

Then in your example, you'd have:

```
int Result = Func();
assert( Result == 1 );
_unused( Result ); // make production build happy
```

That way (a) the production build succeeds, and (b) it is obvious in the code that the variable is unused *by design*, not that it's just been forgotten about. This is especially helpful when parameters to a function are not used.

Comment: Until Result is later used, and then it's just confusing :)  But nice suggestion +1.

Comment: also, Func is still called (unless the optimizer knows it has no side-effects)

Comment: This is a good idea. I am using it for parameters to functions that are not used, but using it for assert()s is certainly a nice option as well.
Maybe a macro called, say, FOR_ASSERT() can be used instead to make the reasoning clear.
Thanks!

Comment: Fine, but a little verbose in this case. It is possible to avoid the intermediate variable.

Comment: @xtofl: That's a point, but almost certainly you *want* Func() to be called -- otherwise you could have just written "assert(Func() == 1);" in the first place.

Comment: You can also make your `assert` a macro like: `#define assert(X,Y) __assert(X,Y); _unused(X)` where X is your variable and Y the condition. Usage in your case: `assert(Result, 1);`

Comment: You'll need to use a different name. Identifiers at global scope (which macros count as) are not allowed to begin with an underscore. This is reserved for the implementation. Macros are also typically in ALL_UPPERCASE to avoid clashing with regular variables.

Comment: I use CANBE_UNUSED(v) to emphasise that the use is conditional on #if evaluation though I do also like the @Gui13 suggestion.

Answer (score 36):

I wouldn't be able to give a better answer than this, that addresses that problem, and many more:

[Stupid C++ Tricks: Adventures in assert](http://web.archive.org/web/20201129200055/http://cnicholson.net/2009/02/stupid-c-tricks-adventures-in-assert/)

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define ASSERT(x) do { (void)sizeof(x);} while (0)
#else
#include <assert.h>
#define ASSERT(x) assert(x)
#endif
```

Comment: For the lazy, in release builds: #define ASSERT(X) do { (void)sizeof(x); } while(0)

Comment: I like this better because it works even in the case where `x` is **not** a variable. So you don't have to use a different macro depending on what you assert... Also the link is definitely wort the read.

Answer (score 35):

As of C++17, the variable can be decorated with an attribute.

```
[[maybe_unused]] int Result = Func();
assert( Result == 1 );
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused for details.

This is better than the `(void)Result` trick because you directly decorate the variable declaration, rather than add something as an afterthought.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that "recent C++" == since C++17

Answer (score 10):

You could create another macro that allows you to avoid using a temporary variable:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define Verify(x) assert(x)
#else
#define Verify(x) ((void)(x))
#endif

// asserts that Func()==1 in debug mode, or calls Func() and ignores return
// value in release mode (any braindead compiler can optimize away the comparison
// whose result isn't used, and the cast to void suppresses the warning)
Verify(Func() == 1);
```

Comment: This solves the original problem, is very neat and easy to understand, and also avoids a whole class of bugs where debug builds execute different code to release builds. Is there a reason it doesn't have more up votes? Are there gotchas anyone is aware of?

Comment: This doesn't work if you do `int s = Fun(); Verify(s == 1)` because many compilers will complain that `s` is set but unused. Even the `(void)(x)` trick doesn't work (Intel compiler, 2017 version).

Comment: @MarkLakata: That seems like a defect in the Intel compiler.  I haven't seen that type of problem with any compilers I've ever worked with, though admittedly I've never used the Intel compiler.  I'd wager that you could work around it by explicitly adding a useless `(void)s` afterwards, but that's clearly suboptimal.

Answer (score 9):

```
int Result = Func();
assert( Result == 1 );
```

This situation means that in release mode, you really want:

```
Func();
```

But `Func` is non-void, i.e. it returns a result, i.e. it is a **query**.

Presumably, besides returning a result, `Func` modifies something (otherwise, why bother calling it and not using its result?), i.e. it is a **command**.

By the **command-query separation principle**, `Func` shouldn't be a command and a query at the same time. In other words, queries shouldn't have side effects, and the "result" of commands should be represented by the available queries on the object's state.

```
Cloth c;
c.Wash(); // Wash is void
assert(c.IsClean());
```

Is better than

```
Cloth c;
bool is_clean = c.Wash(); // Wash returns a bool
assert(is_clean);
```

The former doesn't give you any warning of your kind, the latter does.

So, in short, my answer is: don't write code like this :)

**Update (1):** You asked for references about the **Command-Query Separation Principle**. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-Query_Separation) is rather informative. I read about this design technique in [Object Oriented Software Construction, 2nd Editon](http://archive.eiffel.com/doc/oosc/page.html) by Bertrand Meyer.

**Update (2):** j_random_hacker comments "OTOH, every "command" function f() that previously returned a value must now set some variable last_call_to_f_succeeded or similar". This is only true for functions that don't promise anything in their contract, i.e. functions that might "succeed" or not, or a similar concept. With **Design by Contract**, a relevant number of functions will have **postconditions**, so after "Empty()" the object will be "IsEmpty()", and after "Encode()" the message string will be "IsEncoded()", with no need to check. In the same way, and somewhat symetrically, you don't call a special function "IsXFeasible()" before each and every call to a procedure "X()"; because you usually know by design that you're fulfilling X's preconditions at the point of your call.

Comment: This advice is too general. What about `list.Remove`? Here you may *need* to have the return value whether an element was removed. `list.WasSuccessfullyRemoved()` would be bogus.

Comment: Returning an error code from a function is perfectly fine, but you seem to damn the practice.

Comment: @Daniel: Could you explain the rationale for the "command-query separation principle"? A link would be fine. Thanks!

Comment: @j_random_hacker, see Update (1).

Comment: @John: As with all design approaches, the Command-Query Separation Principle is just a technique. A useful technique, IMO, and one that I usually try to follow. I'm ok if in some cases I find out that it is better to go a different way, but it seems that the situation described in the question might be a good candidate for applying it.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for the update. I can see the advantages in this. OTOH, every "command" function f() that previously returned a value must now set some variable last_call_to_f_succeeded or similar, possibly causing problems for re-entrant/multithreaded code (as noted in the article). But yes, CQS definitely seems like a valid, logic-simplifying approach worth applying where possible.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: As with all techniques, it is always subject to evaluation. In many cases, I design like that, but I admit that sometimes I use the other strategy, especially in cases where nothing can be asserted about the result, e.g. "FindFile()" or "UpdateConfigurationFile()". It's just another technique in your toolset, to be used judiciously. However, stay tuned for update (2) :)

Comment: IME, command-query separation doesn't help you as much if you store the result of a query to verify it _later_.  (E.g., that a list has shortened in length or that a computed value is the same before and after a supposedly invariant transformation.)  Rerunning the query inside the `assert()` doesn't help because you need to assert against the value of the query from some previous point in time.

Comment: You make it sound like I have a choice.  I'm often calling functions that other people have written.  For example I use pthread_mutex_init() and pthread_mutex_destroy().  I can't choose to call was_mutex_initialized_properly() or was_mutex_destroyed() because they don't exist!  https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init

Comment: I was once a huge fan of Eiffel and DbC and Command-Query separation and then we got multithreading and Command-Query separation  just became the worst design pattern.

Comment: @Lothar in OOSC/2 there is already multithreading. Chapter 30 is "Concurrency, distribution, client-server and the internet". Meyer discusses CQS in that context: "You will remember the division of features into commands (procedures), which perform some transformation on the target object, and queries (functions and attributes) which return information about it. Command calls do not need to wait, but query calls may (...) These observations yield the basic concept of wait by necessity: once a separate call has started, a client only needs to wait for its termination if the call is to a query

Comment: @Lothar (continued) "Wait by necessity: If a client has started one or more calls on a certain separate object, and it executes on that object a call to a query, that call will only proceed after all the earlier ones have been completed, and any further client operations will wait for the query call to terminate." (page 989)

Comment: @Lother (continued) Page 1029 discusses "Support for command-query separation It is commonly believed that the principle cannot hold in a concurrent context, as for example you cannot write `next_element := buffer.item; buffer.remove;` and have the guarantee that the element removed by the second call is the same that the first instruction assigned to next_item. (...) This argument is plainly wrong. It is confusing two notions: exclusive access and routine specification. With the notation of this chapter, it is easy to obtain exclusive access
without sacrificing the CQS principle."

Answer (score 6):

With C++17 we can do:

```
[[maybe_unused]] int Result = Func();
```

though it involves a bit of extra typing compared to a assert substitution. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486904/how-do-i-best-silence-a-warning-about-unused-variables?rq=1).

Note: Added this because is the first google hit for "c++ assert unused variable".

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
Check( Func() == 1 );
```

And implement your Check( bool ) function as you want. It may either use assert, or throw a particular exception, write in a log file or to the console, have different implementations in debug and release, or a combination of all.

Comment: I like this solution.  However, for simplicity and concise, I would suggest `assert(Func() == 1);`  The extra `Check` layer should be up to the programmer.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing is to only declare/assign those variables if the asserts will exist. The `NDEBUG` macro is specifically defined if asserts *won't* be effected (done that way round just because `-DNDEBUG` is a convenient way to disable debugging, I think), so this tweaked copy of @Jardel's answer should work (cf. comment by @AdamPeterson on that answer):

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
int Result =
#endif
Func();
assert(Result == 1);
```

or, if that doesn't suit your tastes, all sorts of variants are possible, e.g. this:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
int Result = Func();
assert(Result == 1);
#else
Func();
#endif
```

In general with this stuff, be careful that there's never a possibility for different translation units to be build with different `NDEBUG` macro states -- especially re. asserts or other conditional content in public header files. The danger is that you, or users of your library might accidentally instantiate a different definition of an inline function from the one used inside the compiled part of the library, quietly violating the [one definition rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) and making the runtime behaviour undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You should move the assert inside the function before the return value(s).  You know that the return value is not an unreferenced local variable.

Plus it makes more sense to be inside the function anyway, because it creates a self contained unit that has its OWN pre- and post-conditions.

Chances are that if the function is returning a value, you should be doing some kind of error checking in release mode on this return value anyway.  So it shouldn't be an unreferenced variable to begin with.

**Edit, But in this case the post condition should be X (see comments):**

I strongly disagree with this point, one should be able to determine the post condition from the input parameters and if it's a member function, any object state. If a global variable modifies the output of the function, then the function should be restructured.

Comment: It could be that Func() is generic enough to be used in multiple places, but *in this case* the return value must be 1. In other cases, other return values may be allowed, so you need to have the assertion here. Unless you want to start passing parameters into Func() to indicate why you're calling it and then have it decide whether to assert, but that seems overly complicated.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Graeme Perrow's comment. This is the situation here.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this point, one should be able to determine the post condition from the input parameters and if it's a member function, any object state. If a global variable modifies the output of the function, then the function should be restructured.

Comment: Re: "Unless you want to start passing parameters into Func() to indicate why you're calling it"  -  Any function's input and current object state should determine its output.  If there is any question of needing to pass why you're calling it to determine the return value, there are major design problems in play.

Comment: Say you're calling an function that returns an integer and in almost all cases, any return value is valid. In this particular case however, the return value must be 1 for whatever reason, and the function you're calling is external or generic enough that it cannot determine that reason. Then the assertion needs to be in the calling function. (cont.)

Comment: Having said that, Brian's right -- if a return code *must* be X, then it's a good idea to have some *non-debug* code in addition to the assertion that handles the case when something other than X is returned.

Comment: Yes - what I'd expect to see would be:
assert(Result);
if(!Result){ //opps - clean up code goes here }

Comment: The main problem with putting the assert inside Func() is that many times you do not have control over Func() - for example if Func() is a Win32 API.  The danger to be careful of here is that in that situation you should probably be handing the error rather than asserting.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Yup I agree, it is not applicable if you don't have control of the func.   But when you do it should be in there.

Answer (score 2):

Most answers suggest using `static_cast<void>(expression)` trick in `Release` builds to suppress the warning, but this is actually suboptimal if your intention is to make checks truly `Debug`-only. The goals of an assertion macro in question are:

1. Perform checks in `Debug` mode
2. Do nothing in `Release` mode
3. Emit no warnings in all cases

The problem is that void-cast approach fails to reach the second goal. While there is no warning, the expression that you've passed to your assertion macro will still be *evaluated*. If you, for example, just do a variable check, that is probably not a big deal. But what if you call some function in your assertion check like `ASSERT(fetchSomeData() == data);` (which is very common in my experience)? The `fetchSomeData()` function will still be called. It may be fast and simple or it may be not.

What you really need is not only warning suppression but perhaps more importantly - **non-evaluation** of the debug-only check expression. This can be achieved with a simple trick that I took from a specialized [Assert](https://github.com/gpakosz/Assert) library:

```
void myAssertion(bool checkSuccessful)
{
   if (!checkSuccessful)
    {
      // debug break, log or what not
    }
}

#define DONT_EVALUATE(expression)                                    \
   {                                                                 \
      true ? static_cast<void>(0) : static_cast<void>((expression)); \
   }

#ifdef DEBUG
#  define ASSERT(expression) myAssertion((expression))
#else
#  define ASSERT(expression) DONT_EVALUATE((expression))
#endif // DEBUG

int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  ASSERT(a == 1);
  ASSERT(performAHeavyVerification());

  return 0;
}
```

All the magic is in the `DONT_EVALUATE` macro. It is obvious that at least *logically* the evaluation of your expression is never needed inside of it. To strengthen that, the C++ standard guarantees that only one of the branches of conditional operator will be evaluated. Here is the quote:

> 5.16 Conditional operator [expr.cond]
>
> *logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression*
>
> Conditional expressions group right-to-left. The first expression is
>   contextually converted to bool. It is evaluated and if it is true, the
>   result of the conditional expression is the value of the second
>   expression, otherwise that of the third expression. Only one of these
>   expressions is evaluated.

I have tested this approach in GCC 4.9.0, clang 3.8.0, VS2013 Update 4, VS2015 Update 4 with the most harsh warning levels. In all cases there are no warnings and the checking expression is never evaluated in `Release` build (in fact the whole thing is completely optimized away). Bare in mind though that with this approach you will get in trouble really fast if you put expressions that have side effects inside the assertion macro, though this is a very bad practice in the first place.

Also, I would expect that static analyzers may warn about "result of an expression is always constant" (or something like that) with this approach. I've tested for this with clang, VS2013, VS2015 static analysis tools and got no warnings of that kind.

Comment: It does emit a warning for Intel 2017.4 `icpc`, if you use `ASSERT( a == 1)` (error #174: expression has no effect)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad use of assert, IMHO. Assert is not meant as an error reporting tool, it's meant to assert preconditions. If Result is not used elsewhere, it's not a precondition.

Comment: In the current place in the code where Func() is called, it is a "can't happen" incident that this function return anything which isn't 1. So an assert() is appropriate here. This isn't error reporting / error checking - it is sanity checking.

Comment: So presumably your application is interested in the side-effects, rather than the return code (as the release code will ignore it)? In that case, I would place an assertion on the side-effects.

Comment: assert can be used for checking preconditions, postconditions, class invariants or intermediate results needed in the implementation.

Comment: @Neil: Suppose Func() is actually printf(), and the return value is the number of characters output -- how could you test the side effects other than by checking the return value?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you use a macro to control your assert definition, such as "_ASSERT". So, you can do this:

```
#ifdef _ASSERT 
int Result =
#endif /*_ASSERT */
Func();
assert(Result == 1);
```

Comment: You should just use the `NDEBUG` macro for this.  Its standard-specified behavior is to be set exactly when `assert()` is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
int Result = Func();
assert( Result == 1 );
Result;
```

This will make the compiler stop complaining about Result not being used.

But you should think about using a version of assert that does something useful at run-time, like log descriptive errors to a file that can be retrieved from the production environment.

Comment: Result; is another warning - which is unused value or has no effect.

Comment: @Mykola Golubyev: Not on VC9 @ Warning Level 4. Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define ASSERT(FUNC, CHECK) assert(FUNC == CHECK)
#else
#define ASSERT(FUNC, CHECK)
#endif

...

ASSERT(Func(), 1);
```

This way, for release build, the compiler don't even need to produce any code for assert.

Comment: In release `Func()` is not called

Comment: For the else case you need "#define ASSERT(FUNC, CHECK) FUNC

Comment: If Func() is required only to return a value for asserting, then in release, the call is not necessary. But yes, otherwise it is necessary and I missed that.

Comment: How does this apply to assertions that are not equality, i.e. `assert( foo.length() < N)` ?

Comment: @MarkLakata: Good question. My solution doesn't cover that.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is inside a function, then act on and return the result:

```
bool bigPicture() {

   //Check the results
   bool success = 1 != Func();
   assert(success == NO, "Bad times");

   //Success is given, so...
   actOnIt();

   //and
   return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Value is always computed.  We also call assert(value) if assertions are
// enabled.  Value is discarded either way.  You do not get a warning either
// way.  This is useful when (a) a function has a side effect (b) the function
// returns true on success, and (c) failure seems unlikely, but we still want
// to check sometimes.
template < class T >
void assertTrue(T const &value)
{
  assert(value);
}

template < class T >
void assertFalse(T const &value)
{ 
  assert(!value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't succeeded in using [[maybe_unused]] but
you can use the unused attribute

```
int Result __attribute__((__unused__)) = Func();
```

[gcc Variable-Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html)