# How can I suppress "unused parameter" warnings in C?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

For instance:

```
Bool NullFunc(const struct timespec *when, const char *who)
{
   return TRUE;
}
```

In C++ I was able to put a `/*...*/` comment around the parameters. But not in C of course, where it gives me the error:

> error: parameter name omitted

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to supress "Unused variable x"-warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417837/what-is-the-best-way-to-supress-unused-variable-x-warning)

Comment: @CiroSantilli This question has more upvotes, it would be better to mark the other question as duplicate.

Comment: See also the [C++ version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1486904/1708801)

Comment: `-Wno-unused-parameter`, it's just too noisy and rarely catches bugs esp. when `-Wshadow` is used.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear `/*...*/` around the parameter name doesn't work in C.  I learned that trick before I made the transition from C to C++.

Answer (score 396, accepted):

I usually write a macro like this:

```
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)
```

You can use this macro for all your unused parameters. (Note that this works on any compiler.)

For example:

```
void f(int x) {
    UNUSED(x);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I just use (void)x directly

Comment: while this is the only portable way AFAIK, the annoyance with this is it can be misleading if you use the variable later and forget ro remove the unused line. this is why GCC's __unused__ is nice.

Comment: @Jog For example, *void f(int UNUSED(x))*, there are compile errors: "variable or field ‘foo’ declared void" and "expected primary-expression before ‘int’".

Comment: @CookSchelling: Ah but you shouldn't use it like that. Do something like this: `void f(int x) {UNUSED(x);}`.

Comment: +1, nice. But I wonder if the parameters are not used at all, why not remove them from the function definition?

Comment: @Alcott because (as in my case) the function might be one of many that have to have the same signature because they are referenced by a function pointer.

Comment: @josch: Could you provide the exact command line you use and your version of GCC? I don't seem to be able to reproduce that warning.

Comment: @Job turned out I was using (void*) instead of (void). The latter works just as you wrote. Deleting my comment.

Comment: I'm using `#define UNUSED(...) (void)(__VA_ARGS__)` which allows me to apply this to multiple variables.

Comment: If using multiple variables, don't you run into *"warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect"* ?

Comment: @LiviuChircu clang 4.0 will give you `warning : expression result unused [-Wunused-value]`

Comment: KEIL 8051 keeps complaining unfortunately, so `#define UNUSED(x) ((x)=(x))` worked better for

Comment: I mean why would I go through the macro torture when I could just do `(void)argsv`
Programming is to make life better not the other way.

Comment: @pasignature: I'd say to make your code self-explanatory. `UNUSED(argsv)` says what it does, `(void)argsv` does not in my opinion.

Comment: @OlegKokorin Thanks to your comment, I started [a library](https://github.com/mentalisttraceur/c-unused) to gather and automatically pick the right `UNUSED` implementation based on compiler. With Keil's compilers, we can use `#ifdef __KEIL__`. If you or anyone else knows of others which need special handling or benefits from a different solution, issues or PRs are welcome!

Answer (score 152):

In GCC, you can label the parameter with the [`unused` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bunused_007d-attribute_002e-2640).

> This attribute, attached to a variable, means that the variable is
> meant to be *possibly* unused. GCC will not produce a warning for this
> variable.

In practice this is accomplished by putting `__attribute__ ((unused))` just before the parameter. For example:

```
void foo(workerid_t workerId) { }
```

becomes

```
void foo(__attribute__((unused)) workerid_t workerId) { }
```

Comment: For any newbies like me, this means putting `__attribute__ ((unused))` in front of the argument.

Comment: @josch I think you are totally correct, but the documentation seems to imply that it should be put *after* the parameter. Both options are probably supported without problems.

Comment: Also note that `__attribute__((unused))` is [a proprietary GCC extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47518775/6296561). It's supported by some other compilers, but I assume this won't work with MSVC. It's not directly a part of the compiler standard though, so this isn't as portable as some other options

Comment: Calling an extension within GCC "proprietary" is, uh, well it's something.

Comment: As a small generalization, `__attribute__ ((unused))  int myUnusedFunc()` gives no unused function warnings

Comment: Thanks, buddy. Adding the dunder attribute (pythonic tone) makes it work perfectly.

Answer (score 74):

You can use GCC or [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang)'s *[unused](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bunused_007d-attribute_002e-2640)* attribute. However, I use these macros in a header to avoid having GCC specific attributes all over the source, also having `__attribute__` everywhere is a bit verbose/ugly.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#  define UNUSED(x) UNUSED_ ## x __attribute__((__unused__))
#else
#  define UNUSED(x) UNUSED_ ## x
#endif

#ifdef __GNUC__
#  define UNUSED_FUNCTION(x) __attribute__((__unused__)) UNUSED_ ## x
#else
#  define UNUSED_FUNCTION(x) UNUSED_ ## x
#endif
```

Then you can do...

```
void foo(int UNUSED(bar)) { ... }
```

*I prefer this because you get an error if you try use `bar` in the code anywhere, so you can't leave the attribute in by mistake.*

And for functions...

```
static void UNUSED_FUNCTION(foo)(int bar) { ... }
```

---

**Note 1):**

As far as I know, [MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) doesn't have an equivalent to `__attribute__((__unused__))`.

**Note 2):**

The `UNUSED` macro won't work for arguments which contain parenthesis, 
so if you have an argument like `float (*coords)[3]` you **can't** do, 
`float UNUSED((*coords)[3])` or `float (*UNUSED(coords))[3]`. This is the only downside to the `UNUSED` macro I found so far, and in these cases I fall back to `(void)coords;`.

Comment: Or maybe just `#define __attribute__(x)` for non-GCC environment (AFAIK none of the `__attribute__` are supported by MSVC)?

Comment: That can work, but dunder prefixed terms are reserved for the compiler so I'd rather avoid this.

Comment: For my gcc at least  putting the attribute specifier before the identifier seems to work right for funcs, vars, and parameter, so something like #define POSSIBLY_UNUSED(identifier) __attribute__((__unused__)) identifier can be used for all three

Comment: When putting it after I get `warning: unused parameter ‘foo’ [-Wunused-parameter]` (gcc 7.3.0)

Comment: UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(p)  is defined in WinNT.h

Answer (score 35):

Seeing that this is marked as gcc you can use the command line switch `Wno-unused-parameter`.

For example:

```
gcc -Wno-unused-parameter test.c
```

Of course this effects the whole file (and maybe project depending where you set the switch) but you don't have to change any code.

Comment: its bad if you just want single parameter not whole file (even if you dont want change the code)

Comment: @Fox, this information is already contained in the answer, why duplicate?

Answer (score 25):

With GCC with the *[unused](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bunused_007d-attribute_002e-2640)* attribute:

```
int foo (__attribute__((unused)) int bar) {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

A gcc/g++ specific way to suppress the unused parameter warning for a block of source code is to enclose it with the following pragma statements:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
<code with unused parameters here>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Clang supports these diagnostic pragmas as well https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas

Answer (score 14):

Since C++ 17, the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute can be used to suppress warnings about unused parameters.

Based on the OP's example code:

```
Bool NullFunc([[maybe_unused]] const struct timespec *when, [[maybe_unused]] const char *who)
{
   return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Note the question specifies C and not C++. This answer will work fine in C++. For anyone tempted to try this with plain old C it will compile without warning (at least using GCC) so it 'works', but tools like clang-tidy will hate it.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem. I used a third-part library. When I compile this library, the compiler (gcc/clang) will complain about unused variables.

Like this

> test.cpp:29:11: warning: variable 'magic' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
>        short magic[] = {
>
> test.cpp:84:17: warning: unused variable 'before_write' [-Wunused-variable]
>            int64_t before_write = Thread::currentTimeMillis();

So the solution is pretty clear. Adding `-Wno-unused` as gcc/clang CFLAG will suppress all "unused" warnings, even thought you have `-Wall` set.

In this way, you DO NOT NEED to change any code.

Comment: This is fine if you actually want to ignore all unused warnings, but that's almost never the case. It's usually just specific instances you want to ignore.

Comment: Your problem is different, in any case. This question is about "unused parameter" warning while you got "unused variable" warning.

Answer (score 5):

Labelling the attribute is ideal way. MACRO leads to sometime confusion.
and by using void(x),we are adding an overhead in processing.

If not using input argument, use

```
void foo(int __attribute__((unused))key)
{
}
```

If not using the variable defined inside the function

```
void foo(int key)
{
   int hash = 0;
   int bkt __attribute__((unused)) = 0;

   api_call(x, hash, bkt);
}
```

Now later using the hash variable for your logic but doesn’t need bkt. define bkt as unused, otherwise compiler says'bkt set bt not used".

NOTE: This is just to suppress  the warning not for optimization.

Comment: You don't add any overhead in processing by using `void(x)`, the compiler will optimize it out.

Answer (score 5):

#### Tell your compiler using a compiler specific nonstandard mechanism

See individual answers for `__attribute__((unused))`, various `#pragma`s and so on. Optionally, wrap a preprocesor macro around it for portability.

#### Switch the warning off

IDEs can signal unused variables visually (different color, or underline). Having that, compiler warning may be rather useless.

In GCC and Clang, add `-Wno-unused-parameter` option at the end of the command line (after all options that switch unused parameter warning on, like `-Wall`, `-Wextra`).

#### Add a cast to void

```
void foo(int bar) {
    (void)bar;
}
```

As per [jamesdlin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417837/what-is-the-best-way-to-suppress-a-unused-variable-x-warning/3418951#3418951) and *[Mailbag: Shutting up compiler warnings](http://herbsutter.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/)*.

#### Do not give the variable a name (C23 and C++ only)

Not allowed in C before the C23 standard, but with a latest compiler (in 2023) and in in C++ (since like forever) one can do

```
void foo(int /*bar*/) {
    ...
}
```

See the [N2480 Allowing unnamed parameters in a function definition (pdf)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2480.pdf) proposal, and check the implementation status at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/compiler_support.

GCC 11, Clang 11, and ICX 2022.2 (oneAPI 2022.3) support this.

#### Use a standard attribute (C23, C++17)

In C++17, there is the [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) attribute which has become part of the standard. Before that, there was `[[gnu::unused]]`. See [clang docs for additional overview](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#maybe-unused-unused). (The `gnu::` attributes in general work in clang as well.)

As part of the C standardization effort bringing closer together C and C++ features, in C23 we get new [attributes in the C language](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/attributes). One of them is [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/attributes/maybe_unused) which works the same as the C++ version. The `[[gnu::unused]]` compiler-specific attribute is not available in versions prior to C23, because earlier C language versions did not have these attributes at all.

Answer (score 1):

In MSVC to suppress a particular warning it is enough to specify the it's number to compiler as /wd#. My CMakeLists.txt contains such the block:

```
If (MSVC)
    Set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "$ {CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} / NODEFAULTLIB: LIBCMT")
    Add_definitions (/W4 /wd4512 /wd4702 /wd4100 /wd4510 /wd4355 /wd4127)
    Add_definitions (/D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
Elseif (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUC)
    Add_definitions (-Wall -W -pedantic)
Else ()
    Message ("Unknown compiler")
Endif ()
```

Now I can not say what exactly /wd4512 /wd4702 /wd4100 /wd4510 /wd4355 /wd4127 mean, because I do not pay any attention to MSVC for three years, but they suppress superpedantic warnings that does not influence the result.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this style being used:

```
if (when || who || format || data || len);
```

Comment: Hm. I cannot say I like this, as this assumes all parameters involved can be converted to a bool.

Comment: This isn't really a good convention, even though the compiler almost certainly will optimize it out, its not really clear whats going on and could confuse static source checkers. better use one of the other suggestions here IMHO.

Comment: I can't believe I'm still getting replies to this. The question stated that it was for C. Yes, in another language this wouldn't work.

Comment: I wouldn't use it but +1 for the novelty factor.

Comment: checking *truth* of variables can give warnings, for structs. eg. `struct { int a; } b = {1}; if (b);` GCC warns, `used struct type value where scalar is required`.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I like Job's answer, but I'm curious about a solution just using the variable name by itself in a "do-nothing" statement:

```
void foo(int x) {
    x; /* unused */
    ...
}
```

Sure, this has drawbacks; for instance, without the "unused" note it looks like a mistake rather than an intentional line of code.

The benefit is that no DEFINE is needed and it gets rid of the warning.

Comment: I either used this with MSVC, but GCC raises "statement without effect" warning. So, Job's solution is the way to go.

Comment: This approach still generates a warning in XCode

Comment: There isn't any one by the name "Job" here. What answer does it refer to? Can you link directly to it? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599160/how-can-i-suppress-unused-parameter-warnings-in-c/15608355#15608355), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: `(void) x; /* unused */` gets rid of the warning for me with GCC 9.3.0

Answer (score -1):

when using the main function in c program and not using the main arguments you can void the arguments as below;

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void)**argv;

    printf("The program has %d arguments\n`enter code here`",argc);

    return (0);
}
```