# Parameter name omitted error?

Tags: c, arrays, function, methods

I am getting an error when trying to call the method:

```
int box(int rows, int cols, int [rows][cols])
```

from the main method using this call:

```
box(arrayDimensions, arrayDimensions, array);
```

But i am not sure what the problem is.

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you show us a fragment of your code that we could try out? Also, what is `int [rows][cols]`?

Comment: Perhaps `int box(int rows, int cols, int ARRAY[rows][cols])`?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey I was gonna go with `YourArrayVariableNameGoesHere` but the shout-out seems to do it justice =P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776810/parameter-name-omitted-c-vs-c

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
int box(int rows, int cols, int [rows][cols])
```

needs to be

```
int box(int rows, int cols, int something[rows][cols])
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, every variable that you use in the function definition/header needs to have an identifier/name. Like anything else, the array you use needs to have an identifier/name, since it is a variable @AkshaiShah modified your code pretty nicely.