# Strange NOOP convention?

Tags: c, pebble-watch

I was browsing a template (at cloudpebble.net) for building a Pebble watch face and came across this code:

```
void handle_minute_tick(AppContextRef ctx, PebbleTickEvent *t) {
  (void)t; // NOOP?
  (void)ctx; // NOOP?

  display_time(t->tick_time);
}


void handle_init(AppContextRef ctx) {
  (void)ctx; // NOOP?

  window_init(&window, "Big Time watch");
  window_stack_push(&window, true);
  window_set_background_color(&window, GColorBlack);

  resource_init_current_app(&APP_RESOURCES);

  // Avoids a blank screen on watch start.
  PblTm tick_time;

  get_time(&tick_time);
  display_time(&tick_time);
}


void handle_deinit(AppContextRef ctx) {
  (void)ctx; // NOOP?

  for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_IMAGE_SLOTS; i++) {
    unload_digit_image_from_slot(i);
  }

}
```

What purpose do the lines I've indicated serve?

Comment: My guess would be just to avoid variable not used warnings.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599160/unused-parameter-warnings-in-c-code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only purpose of those lines is to silence compiler warnings like `-Wunused-parameter`. Note that those variables aren't used anywhere in the function body; casting them to void essentially tells the compiler that that's intentional.

Comment: Note that another (better?) way to do this is to remove their names from the first line of the function, like: `void handle_minute_tick(AppContextRef, PebbleTickEvent *)`

Comment: @StilesCrisis, that's legal in C++, but not in C. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776810/parameter-name-omitted-c-vs-c).

Comment: In this case the parameter `t` *is* actually used, so the `(void)t;` line appears to be a mistake.

Comment: This code is C++. It is declaring variables in the middle of function bodies.

Comment: @StilesCrisis, C99 lets you do that too.

Comment: Is this a generally accepted idiom for suppressing unused parameters now?  Seems like it would be better to use a pragma for that.