# Function with parameter list without variable name

Tags: c++, function-parameter

The following code is very basic and obvious:

```
void PrintParameter(int i, char c)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

If I do this:

```
PrintParameter(5, 'A');
```

I get 5 as expected and because I don't use the parameter `c` no error occurs.

Now I think in a weird thing I expect as being an error:

```
void PrintParameter(int i, char) // declare the type 'char' without the variable
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

I expected an error because of the absence of the variable of type char.

However, instead of an error, I get 5 as before!

This is a bug of my compiler or a compliance with ISO C++ standard?

In case of not being an error this applies only to C++ or to C also?

Comment: This is in perfect compliance with C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik but HOW explain this?

Comment: Actually, G++ with style recommendations allowed (`-Weff-c++`, I think) warns you if you *don't* omit the unused parameter.

Comment: It's an unnamed parameter, it's perfectly fine to have them. They're useful to explicitly state that you are not using an argument of the method, without having any warnings about it.

Comment: Are there any situations where you'd _want_ to do this? Ah, yes. When forward declaring something without variable names.

Comment: It's different between C and C++, illegal in the former. Relevant citations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8776886/1537925).

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson: yes: implementing a virtual method, but not using one of the parameters because implementation does not require it (bad design? maybe)

Comment: @user7140484 does *what* apply to C? It is not C code. And I am pretty sure you have not found a compiler bug.

Comment: There are plenty of situations where you want to do this in C++. Specifically in situations that involve overloading or specialization, where an overloaded operator or a specialized function/class method does not need to use a particular parameter.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson, I don't want to use this anywhere, because I don't even know this is possible. I just try to catch a bug and I get a surprise.

Comment: @WeatherVane, ok, just replace the `cout`s with `printf`s

Comment: @user7140484 with `printf(i);`? ); Deleted C tag.

Comment: @WeatherVane, `printf("%d", i)` as you know

Comment: @user7140484 MSVC compiling a C source says of `void PrintParameter(int i, char)` *"error C2055: expected formal parameter list, not a type list"* as you could have found out yourself ;)

Comment: @I'm using a C++ compiler and I don't know if C++ compilers behave exactly as C compilers when in presence of plain C code.

Comment: @WeatherVane, sorry I don't read your full answer before.