# How to silence unused command line argument error with clang without disabling it?

Tags: c, clang

When using `-Werror` with clang, it transforms "warning: argument unused during compilation" messages into errors, which makes sense. There's a `-Qunused-arguments` flag to silence them entirely. My question is, is there some `-Wno-error=...` flag I can pass to make these not be errors, without disabling them entirely?

Comment: `unused-arguments` is about unused command line flags, not arguments in code.

Comment: Which argument precisely is unused on the command line?

Comment: Please show the whole command line and the whole message produced by clang.

Comment: Is the code your own? If so, then I would advice you to prevent the warning in the source code itself. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599160/unused-parameter-warnings-in-c-code

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Turns out the correct answer is `-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument`.

Comment: This seems necessary when runnning Clang with `-stdlib=libc++` through `distcc`.

Comment: Seems to have changed  clang9 now uses -Qunused-arguments.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use this command:

```
-Wno-unused-command-line-argument
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had similar issues with autoconf while using clang-8 compiler in ./configure.

```
*clang-8: error: unknown argument: '-ftree-loop-distribute-patterns'*
*clang-8: error: unknown argument: '-fno-semantic-interposition'*
```

I needed following command line to fix these errors:

```
./configure CC=clang-8 CXX=clang++-8 LD=clang++-8 CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

Hope this is helpful to others.

Comment: Thanks for showing an example. This, however, does not work for `clang++` (I know the question tagged `c`. Just wanted to make it clear for anyone trying it for C++). https://godbolt.org/z/GqodhYWv7

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019, open the property pages of the C++ Project and go to Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> CommandLine.

In the "Additional Options" text box, paste

> -Wunused-command-line-argument

Do this for each configuration / platform combination.  This worked for me, to turn off only this warning.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--start-no-unused-arguments` and `--end-no-unused-arguments` to silence the warning only for *some* arguments.

This is convenient for flags like `-stdlib` (warns if used with C code), `-rtlib` and `-unwindlib` (warn if used during compilation as opposed to linking).