# Debug code and C++ unused parameter warning

Tags: c++

I have search the solutions for C/C+ unused variable warning, and none fits my need. Here's the situation:

I am developing algorithms on PC, and will then port it to the real embedded platform.  The PC version will have debug codes showing images on a monitor of a PC.  The embedded platform, unfortunately, does not have a monitor.  Of course the embedded platform does not need those debug code at all.

To distinguish the code, we can do this:

```
#ifndef EMBEDED
   MyDebugCode(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
#endif
```

However, I decide that this is too lousy, since there are so many calls of those debug functions.  Those `EMBEDED` conditionals will pollute the code. Instead, I try to write the conditional compile flag inside the debug function like below:

```
inline void MyDebugCode(type1 p1, type2 p2, type3 p3)
{
#ifndef EMBEDED
     DisplaySomethingOnMonitor(p1, p2, p3);
     ...
     ...
     ...
#endif
}
```

So that I can write the `#ifndef/#ifdef` once, in the function, and call it many times without those `#ifndef/#ifdef`.

Now when `EMBEDED` is defined, we will get unused varaible `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`.  This is the problem.

In addition, I am hoping the `inline` can be totally optimized out the whole debug function, as if it does not exist, when `EMBEDDED` is defined. This is secondary though.

Anyone has better solutions/practices?

Please note that those parameters can be references to class instances.

The compiler is g++

Comment: Doesn't your compiler have pragmas to ignore specific warnings for specific files?

Comment: I forget to search pragmas of g++ ... Wait...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unused parameter warnings in C code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3599160/1708801)

Comment: What about `#ifdef EMBEDED` `inline void MyDebugCode(type1, type2, type3) {}` `#else` ... - sane compilers should not warn about unused anonymous parameters (because that's the whole point of anonymous parameters).

Comment: @immibis: Wa!  It's my blind spot. I can't believe I just neglect such a simple solution...  Please post it as an answer, I will close this question!

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour: This is not quite a duplicate.  This special case has a simpler solution, like immibis said. Yet I am considering my secondary requirement (which is also a difference from the 'possible duplicate') now.  It seems that the "optimize out" is not performed by g++, for immibis's solution.  I will try more optimization options of g++ then.

Comment: @RobinHsu reposted as an answer (because it's an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your compiler has no other way to disable the warning, this should work:

```
#ifdef EMBEDED
inline void MyDebugCode(type1, type2, type3) {}
#else
inline void MyDebugCode(type1 p1, type2 p2, type3 p3)
{
    DisplaySomethingOnMonitor(p1, p2, p3);
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
#endif
```

Any reasonable compiler shouldn't warn on unused unnamed parameters, because there is no way to use them.

Answer (score 1):

One possibly inelegant but common way to do this is to make `MyDebugCode` a macro which expands to nothing if it is undesired. A simple case would be:

```
#ifdef EMBEDDED
#  define MyDebugCode(a,b,c)
#else
inline void MyDebugCode(type1 p1, type2 p2, type3 p3)
{
     DisplaySomethingOnMonitor(p1, p2, p3);
     ...
     ...
     ...
}
#endif
```

(Some people would prefer to make `MyDebugCode` always a macro, either doing nothing or invoking a function with possibly a different name. YMMV.)

Comment: Ya. I known this, and is considering this solution.  The problem is that, the function is in a namespace.  where `#define  MyNameSpace::MyDebugCode(a,b,c)` won't work.  Yet I am considering to move it out of namespace, or by using `use namespace MyNameSpace;` to overcome this problem.  Thanks anyway.