# How to disable multiple GCC compilation warnings?

Tags: c, gcc, pragma

I have a chunk of code that I can disable compilation warnings for via pragmas, like the following example that disables a defined-but-not-used compilation warning:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-function"
static int
bs_qd_debug_kv(void* cls, enum MHD_ValueKind kind, const char* key, const char* value)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "key [%s] -> value [%s]\n", key, value);
    return MHD_YES;
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

This works fine, but how can I disable multiple warnings?

For instance, I get a defined-but-not-used compilation warning with the following two pragmas:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-function"
static int
bs_qd_debug_kv(void* cls, enum MHD_ValueKind kind, const char* key, const char* value)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "key [%s] -> value [%s]\n", key, value);
    return MHD_YES;
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Is there a different arrangement of `#pragma` directives, which allows specification of multiple pragmas on the enclosed code?

**EDIT**

Upon reading the linked question, it seems that question is almost entirely different from this one. This question asks about the use of multiple GCC-specific pragmas. The linked question asks about a compiler response to pragmas from OpenMP. I'm not sure that the two questions are identical, even though they both tangentially touch on the use of pragmas with GCC.

Comment: just tested with gcc 6.2.1 and I get no warnings, even when using `-Wall`. If I remove the ununsed function pragma, I get the warning... BTW you could [edit] your post to only include base types & values so it would really be a [mcve], which isn't right now.

Comment: I am using GCC 4.8.5 and upgrading is not an option. If this is a "bug" with how GCC 4.8.5 handles pragmas, that's fine, if I can get some confirmation of this behavior. I do not get these warnings with Apple's current build of Clang, either (8.1.0), so I recognize this may be a GCC-specific issue and have tagged the question so.

Comment: This is a known bug.  See the linked dup.

Comment: @AlexReynolds if you cannot upgrade, you can always silence the unused parameter warnings using `(void)parameter` or attr ununused: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599160/unused-parameter-warnings-in-c-code so in your case, you only have 1 pragma warning to use.

Comment: also note that `-Wunused-parameter` isn't included in `-Wall` option in 6.2

Comment: See if the answer to the supposed duplicate actually answers your question