# What is (void)(ar) when ar is a struct

Tags: c++, embedded

```
static int ModifyStatus(struct LinkService* ar, const char* property, char* value, int len)
{
    (void)(ar);

    if (property == NULL || value == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    /* modify status property*/
    printf("Modify Receive property: %s(value=%s[%d])\n", property, value,len);
    if (strcmp(property,"CarControl") == 0) {
        g_car_control_mode = CAR_DIRECTION_CONTROL_MODE;
        car_direction_control_func(value);
    } else if (strcmp(property, "ModularControl") == 0) {
        g_car_control_mode = CAR_MODULE_CONTROL_MODE;
        car_modular_control_func(value);
    } else if (strcmp(property, "SpeedControl") == 0) {
        g_car_control_mode = CAR_SPEED_CONTROL_MODE;
        car_speed_control_func(value);
    } 

    /*
     * if Ok return 0,
     * Otherwise, any error, return StatusFailure
     */
    return 0;
}
```

I can't understand this stand for what when ar is a struct.
Thanks very much. I consider it as a function point before. Thanks again.

Comment: It "uses" `ar` and eliminates a compiler warning. You could get the same by changing the function definition to `static int ModifyStatus(struct LinkService* , const char* property, char* value, int len)` to tell the compiler ahead of time that we aren't using that parameter.

Comment: `ar` in your posted code is not a struct but a pointer.

Comment: Please remove the *Also I want to know how does Histream app interact with hi3861 via wifi.* as that is a radically different topic. A question should ask only one question.

Comment: `ar` is a pointer not a struct.

Answer (score 6):

The cast to `(void)` suppresses the compiler from warning that `ar` is unused. Sometimes, you may need a function to have a certain signature to conform to an interface, but not actually need to use all of the arguments. This is especially useful if your codebase uses `-Werror`.

Also see: [How to suppress "unused parameter" warnings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599160/)