# What is the aim of `(void) a;`?

Tags: c, types, casting

I discovered in the SDL2 sources something weird.

```
while (renderer->textures) {
    SDL_Texture *tex = renderer->textures; (void) tex;
    SDL_DestroyTexture(renderer->textures);
    SDL_assert(tex != renderer->textures);  /* satisfy static analysis. */
}
```

The loop itself is just a linked list iteration (`SDL_DestroyTexture`modifies `renderer->textures`).
But there is `(void) tex;` which I don't understand : it seems like a cast to void, but what is the objective ? `tex` is just a pointer so there is no need to evaluate it, and the return value of the cast isn't stored (if storing `void` is even possible ...).

Thanks for anyone helping !

Comment: @UnholySheep Here `tex` isn't a function parameter and it is used after

Comment: Related info: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/777359/509868)

Comment: It's a way to silence warnings of the form "warning: 'tex' is unused in function 'blahblahblah'".

Comment: @anatolyg Thanks ! is there a way to set your link as the duplicate one instead of the current one ?

Comment: @JulienVernay You're asking for an existing question to be marked as duplicate and reference yours?

Comment: In case someone wants to vote for the other link, here is the link to that other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/777261/509868